# Slider with Synchronized Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is what I have created so far:
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU3VE.png)

Basically you start off with the red div on the left with the red circle that is active on the right. When you click on the blue circle, for example, you get the div on the left to turn blue and then the blue circle gets active and the red circle gets inactive. Here is how it looks after clicking on the blue circle: [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv8Rl.png)

And of course, if you click on the green circle the div on the left turns green if you click on the black circle the div on the left turns black.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#circle-2').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-1').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-3').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-4').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('.rect').removeClass('rect-1').removeClass('rect-3').removeClass('rect-4').addClass('rect-2')
    })

    $('#circle-1').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-2').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-3').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-4').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('.rect').removeClass('rect-2').removeClass('rect-3').removeClass('rect-4').addClass('rect-1')
    })

    $('#circle-3').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-1').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-2').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-4').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('.rect').removeClass('rect-1').removeClass('rect-2').removeClass('rect-4').addClass('rect-3')
    })

    $('#circle-4').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-1').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-2').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('#circle-3').removeClass('active-circle')
        $('.rect').removeClass('rect-1').removeClass('rect-2').removeClass('rect-3').addClass('rect-4')
    })
})
```

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.rect {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.rect-1 {
    background: red;
}

.rect-2 {
    background: blue;
}

.rect-3 {
    background: green;
}

.rect-4 {
    background: black;
}

.circle {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    opacity: .25;
}

.circle-color-1 {
    background-color: red;
}

.circle-color-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.circle-color-3 {
    background-color: green;
}

.circle-color-4 {
    background-color: black;
}

.active-circle {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="rect rect-1">

        </div>
        <div class="circles-container">
            <div id="circle-1" class="circle circle-color-1 active-circle">Circle 1</div>
            <div id="circle-2" class="circle circle-color-2">Circle 2</div>
            <div id="circle-3" class="circle circle-color-3">Circle 3</div>
            <div id="circle-4" class="circle circle-color-4">Circle 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
```

Now here is where I am struggling. I want the div on the left to switch color automatically every 3 seconds and of course, the circles on the right should match that as well. So we start with the div on the left being red and the red circle on the right being active and after 3 seconds the div changes to blue and the active circle is the blue one. Basically what I have now but happening automatically without having to click on the circles and keeping the click functionality as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first priority, aside from achieving the automatic cycle through the elements, is to DRY up your code. Given that all that changes between the multiple repeated event handlers is the class you add, you can remove the `id` attributes and target the elements by their common `.circle` class. You can then bind a single event handler which works for all elements and applies the class to `.rect` which is stored in a `data` attribute on each element.

To create the cycle effect you can use `setInterval()`, targeting the next element from the one which currently has `.active-circle`. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $rect = $('.rect');
  var $circles = $('.circle').on('click', setActiveCircle);
  $circles.first().trigger('click');
  
  function setActiveCircle() {
    $circles.removeClass('active-circle');
    $(this).addClass('active-circle');
    $rect.removeClass('rect-1 rect-2 rect-3 rect-4').addClass($(this).data('rect'));
  }
  
  setInterval(function() {
    let $targetCircle = $circles.filter('.active-circle').next();
    if ($targetCircle.length === 0)
      $targetCircle = $circles.first();
      
    setActiveCircle.call($targetCircle);
  }, 3000);  
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.rect {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.rect-1 { background: red; }
.rect-2 { background: blue; }
.rect-3 { background: green; }
.rect-4 { background: black; }

.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  opacity: .25;
}

.circle-color-1 { background-color: red; }
.circle-color-2 { background-color: blue; }
.circle-color-3 { background-color: green; }
.circle-color-4 { background-color: black; }

.active-circle { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="circles-container">
    <div class="circle circle-color-1" data-rect="rect-1">Circle 1</div>
    <div class="circle circle-color-2" data-rect="rect-2">Circle 2</div>
    <div class="circle circle-color-3" data-rect="rect-3">Circle 3</div>
    <div class="circle circle-color-4" data-rect="rect-4">Circle 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's really helpful! I cannot appreciate it enough!